# Does AdS/CFT correspondence apply to entire AdS space or those covered by Poincare patch?

Tags: ads-cft, holographic-principle, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am getting confused as I study the AdS/CFT correspondence, so I ask this question. CFT is given on the conformal boundary of AdS, which can be derived from Poincare coordinate patch to AdS. Would this mean that CFT has its AdS dual only on the subspace covered by this Poincare coordinate patch? Or does CFT has its AdS dual on the entire AdS space?